# How to add limit when echoing images from a directory folder?

Tags: php, directory, glob

Below is a script that echoes out all images from a directory folder, it works with no issues. However, I'm simply trying to limit the number of images echoed to 8 or less. Any help is appreciated.

PHP:

```html
$files = glob("images/*.*");
    
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++){
  $image = $files[$i];
  $supported_file = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png'
  );
    
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
    echo '<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-4">';   
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image"  class="your_images" />'."<br /><br />";
    echo '</div>';   
  } else {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
in this, set $i<=8;

Comment: i did not find any while loop?

Comment: for ($i=1; $i<8); $i++) have tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Raman allready stated a simple modification to the for will do it

```
$maxImages = 8;

for ($i=1; $i<=count($files) && $i<=$maxImages; $i++) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

You need to have the image count in case you do not have 8 images in your folder

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$limit = 8; // number of images
$start = 0;// or $start = count($$files)-$limit)
$files = glob("images/*.{jpeg,jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
$limit = ((count($files))>$limit)? $limit : count($files);// to take into account situation where we have less than 8 images
foreach(array_slice($files,$start, $limit) as $image){ 
echo '<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-4">';   
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image"  class="your_images"     />'."<br/><br/>";
    echo '</div>';   
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would you check if the directory is empty before displaying the images?

Comment: you can use if(count($files)==0){}; 
}